# How to create custom form control using native element HTMLElement in angular 5 6 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

it is practically the following
I want the native HTML input tag to extend the native and typescript properties

example: 
from:

```html
<input type="checkbox"
       formControlName="aComponent"
       name="aComponent"
       [checked]="data.get('aComponent').value">
```

to:

```html
<my-input type="checkbox"
       formControlName="aComponent"
       name="aComponent"
       [checked]="data.get('aComponent').value">
```

or

```html
<my-input type="checkbox"
       formControlName="aComponent"
       name="aComponent"
       [checked]="data.get('aComponent').value"> </my-input>
```

[checked] and formControlName is a property that provides angular, which also would like to inherit and native features such as: type and name

I know it's a little crazy but I would like to know if it is possible

in my component I try to do the following but, it only imports the native elements of HTML but not the features that Angular provides

```html
import {Component, ElementRef, Inject, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-input',
    templateUrl: './input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./input.component.css']
})
export class MyInputComponent extends HTMLElement implements OnInit {

    @Input() checked; // angular feature that does not work

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ControlValueAccessor` in order to use formControlName and ngModel to your component.

The below two tutorials will definitely help you to create custom form controls.

[ControlValueAccsor to act your component as a form control](https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83)

[Using ControlValueAccessor to create custom form controls](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/)

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Inject, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-input',
    templateUrl: './input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./input.component.css']
})
export class MyInputComponent extends HTMLElement implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor{

    @Input() checked; // angular feature that does not work

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

 private innerValue: T;

  private changed = new Array<(value: T) => void>();
  private touched = new Array<() => void>();

  get value(): T {
    return this.innerValue;
  }

  set value(value: T) {
    if (this.innerValue !== value) {
      this.innerValue = value;
      this.changed.forEach(f => f(value));
    }
  }

  writeValue(value: T) {
    this.innerValue = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: T) => void) {
    this.changed.push(fn);
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void) {
    this.touched.push(fn);
  }

  touch() {
    this.touched.forEach(f => f());
  }

}
```